# Place DataBand in a certain space

Tags: report, stimulsoft

Im making a report with Stimulsoft Designer, and I place a lot of information. Now I need to place a data band for showing a list of phones in a certain space, but the only position on which the data band appears is on top (after header) and full width. That's not what I need, I need something like this:

[image]

I tried to create a "Data" square, and other options shown there, but it doesn't work. What I'am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a panel with that shape, and insert the databand inside the panel